# Make a Field available only when a value from a Hierarchical Select is chosen

Tags: select, drupal-7, content-type

I am using a Hierarchical Select that enables a user to first select a continent ( first select ) and then a country ( second select )

I wish however to enable a field ( text ) only when a user selects

North America (select 1) -> USA (select 2)

Hoping someone could explain how i go around doing this.

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can try with module "[field conditional state](https://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state)".

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [Conditional fields module](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). This module define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.

If you need more details Please read the https://www.drupal.org/node/1704126

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.